# How to format a print booklet with fold out tabs on certain pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I am creating a sort of portfolio book for an interior design company. They requested the sections have fold out tabs on the pages. I've never had to make something like this before so I am trying to figure out the best way to set up the document. Is there a way for me to set this up in my InDesign file, or do I need to set it up as a separate file for the printer to insert on printing?

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail and context. How are those tabs meant to fold out of the pages? Top or sideways? I have seen and used many tabs, but very rarely come accross fold-out tabs. Maybe give us a draft illustration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's not clear what is meant by "fold out tabs". More information about the binding method, format etc. is also required to be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can set it up yourself, by making the tabbed pages wider by a set length and drawing a guideline at the fold.

It's better and easier if you start with a template. Your printing service may have templates for folding page booklets.

There are many document booklet templates available online, someone even come in InDesign files.

https://www.google.com/search?q=fold+out+tab+booklet+template&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS698US698&oq=fold+out+tab+booklet+template&aqs=chrome..69i57.8943j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score -5):

You can always use Adobe Illustrator for these kind of works. You just need to Create Artboards and boom! You can edit, review , layout and design your stuff.